# Microsoft ActiveX Controls

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Is there a way to change the index value of a ActiveX Button that inserted onto a spreadsheet. I currently have four buttons and two are hidden and two are visible. I would like to re-order the them to not have a large gap between objects. I have some VBA code that runs when the document is opened to ensure that they are the right size and location. Because it loops through the OLEObjects Collection; it will not matter what order they are in on the spreadsheet they will always appear with a gap because of the index value in the OLE Object collection. Below is the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.EvaluateToError = False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SITE").Activate

Dim button As OLEObject
Dim name As String, top As Integer

top = 15

For Each button In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SITE").OLEObjects
    Debug.Print button.name & " " & button.ZOrder
    name = button.name
    If button.OLEType = xlButtonOnly And InStr(name, "btn") = 1 Then
        With button
            .Height = 21.75
            .Width = 174.75
            .Left = 1114.5
            .top = top
        End With
        top = top + 30
    End If
Next button

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need to change the index of ActiveX controls? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: @Kyle I would like to change the index value of the controls because with the above code; if I rearrange the buttons on the spreadsheet then when the code runs it changes the arrangement back. I still need the code because without it I run I to the issue of the buttons re-sizing and moving upon reopening of the document

Comment: Can you just change the name and work off names?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think of changing the object names. Although, for future reference is there a way to change the object index value?

Comment: I don't believe you can actually adjust the index of the objects.

Comment: @Kyle Well that sucks!

Comment: @TroyPilewsky, did you try my code?

Comment: @user3598756 No, I have not tried it yet. I made the change that Kyle suggested. In order for me to try your code I would have to deviate from the standard Hungarian Notation for object names.

Comment: @TroyPilewsky, to hell with hungarian notation if it prevents you an easy solution! But maybe I didn't get your real issue. Would you add some more info and examples?

Comment: @user3598756 I have four ActiveX buttons on a spreadsheet. Over time, two of the buttons have become obsolete. What I did was change visible property to false for the obsolete buttons. What I start with was:

Comment: @user3598756 All Buttons: <img src="https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxo3lawT8d-1S29fMWtBUGpteEE width="100" height="100"> Two Visible: <img src="https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxo3lawT8d-1enhGbnd3YkVNRFU width="100" height="100"> Two Visible Correct: <img src="https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxo3lawT8d-1MnpsZ2ZoNmlxcms width="100" height="100">

Comment: @TroyPilewsky, I can't see anything. You can add images to your post

Comment: @user3598756 Its fixed!

Answer (score 0):

If you give them proper names with an integer code in it reflecting their intended position (e.g.: "btn...01", "btn...02",...) then you could try this code (sorry for not being able to format it as code by now):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.EvaluateToError = False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SITE").Activate

Dim button As OLEObject
Dim name As String
Dim btnRnk As Long

For Each button In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SITE").OLEObjects
    name = button.name
    If button.OLEType = xlButtonOnly And InStr(name, "btn") = 1 Then
        btnRnk = CLng(Right(name,2))
        With button
            .Height = 21.75
            .Width = 174.75
            .Left = 1114.5
            .top = 15 + (btnRank - 1) * 30
        End With
    End If
Next button

End Sub
```

Comment: @TroyPilewsky, did you get through it with this code?